# How to mount partition of .img as loop back device Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, loop-device

I need to create a bootable disk image on a remote computer but keep getting errors trying to mount partitions created on the .img file

I have tried many different utilities but the basic steps I am follow are

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=rootfs.img bs=1024 count=1M

1048576+0 records in
1048576+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB, 1.0 GiB) copied, 11.1241 s, 96.5 MB/s

$ sudo losetup -f --show rootfs.img
/dev/loop4

$ export DISK=/dev/loop4

$ sudo sfdisk ${DISK} <<-__EOF__
4M,,L,*
__EOF__
Checking that no-one is using this disk right now ... OK

Disk /dev/loop4: 1 GiB, 1073741824 bytes, 2097152 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

>>> Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xfe3f011f.
/dev/loop4p1: Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 1020 MiB.
/dev/loop4p2: Done.

New situation:
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xfe3f011f

Device       Boot Start     End Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/loop4p1 *     8192 2097151 2088960 1020M 83 Linux

The partition table has been altered.
Calling ioctl() to re-read partition table.
Re-reading the partition table failed.: Invalid argument
The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot or after you run partprobe(8) or kpartx(8).
Syncing disks.

$ sudo kpartx -av ${DISK}
add map loop4p1 (253:0): 0 2088960 linear 7:4 8192

$ lsblk
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0       7:0    0 33.3M  1 loop /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
loop1       7:1    0 55.5M  1 loop /snap/core18/1997
loop2       7:2    0 70.4M  1 loop /snap/lxd/19647
loop3       7:3    0 32.3M  1 loop /snap/snapd/11588
loop4       7:4    0    1G  0 loop
└─loop4p1 253:0    0 1020M  0 part
xvda      202:0    0    8G  0 disk
└─xvda1   202:1    0    8G  0 part /
xvdb      202:16   0   32G  0 disk

$ sudo mount ${DISK}p1 /mnt/rootfs/
mount: /mnt/rootfs: special device /dev/loop4p1 does not exist.
```

This seems really simple but obviously I have not been able to put together right combination of steps yet.

Comment: Does `/dev/mapper/loop4p1` exist instead? See the example in `man 8 kpartx`.

Comment: it exists but gives: "mount: /mnt/rootfs: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/loop5p1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error." if I try and mount it instead of the /mnt/ device

Comment: `mount` mounts a *filesystem*. You did not use `mkfs.whatever` and there is no filesystem in the device you want to mount. Partitions and filesystems are different concepts.